# CruiseControl.Net plugin for nunit3

Tags: nunit, cruisecontrol.net

It seems that the syntax for running nunit has changed between nunit 2 and 3. I  would like to move my existing CruiseControl.Net configuration to use NUnit 3, but I cannot work out how to modify my existing  target (see below) to use nunit3. Is there documentation anywhere? Thanks for any help.

```
<nunit>
 <environment>
     <variable name="TEST_FILES_DIRECTORY" value="C:\TestPlans\TestFiles" />
 </environment>
 <path>C:\nunit3\Compiled\nunit3-console.exe</path>
 <assemblies>
     <assembly>C:\source\TestRunner\bin\Debug\Tests.dll</assembly>
 </assemblies>
 <includedCategories>
     <includedCategory>Data</includedCategory>
 </includedCategories>
 <timeout>72000</timeout>
</nunit>
```

Comment: I doubt it is going to work unless you keep it to the bare bones (skip categories) because the command line parameters for NUnit 3 are different than for NUnit 2. The CC.NET plugin will be executing the NUnit console process with command line options, but will be passing the wrong ones.

Comment: We run our NUnit 3 tests with a straight command line task in CC.NET

Comment: Yes, that's what I found, and so temporarily I am running just a command line task. It would be nice if there were an nunit3 task but I couldn't find anything about one. Thanks!

Comment: It probably wouldn't be too hard to fork the NUnit 2 task and update it with the new command line. I've done the same for other systems in a few hours.

Comment: I would be happy to try to do that. Where is the repo for the nunit task? I should say that I have never worked on a task before, but am reasonably comfortable with C#.

Comment: I'm on my phone right now, so don't have a link to the repo. The NUnit task ships with CC.NET, so it should be in that repo. You shouldn't have any problems working on it. I've written tasks from scratch before and they were pretty easy. Ping me if you have issues.

Comment: Just FYI - the last pull request accepted to CruiseControl was in 2015, unfortunately the project seems to be unmaintained. We're in the same position, and have resigned ourselves to using the Exec task. Of course, forking CC.NET, and running a custom version is also always an option!

Comment: I've written an NUnit3 task. I have it committed to a local branch. If I push this to GitHub, should I make it a pull request and assign it to you (Rob Prouse)? It's a very basic task that only supports a small set of the Nunit3 features, but may be useful.

Comment: I've tried pushing my branch to the ccnet/CruiseControl.NET repo, but I think I need to be granted permission to do this. How do I go about doing this?